# CORS ORIGIN issue with different domains

Tags: cors-anywhere

I am using **CodeIgniter** REST API with Angular frontend.

I tried to fetch and post data with REST API, but **CORS** error occurs in console, and I installed chrome CORS extension and enabled to solve the problem.

When I moved files to the remote host, same error occurs again.

Files hosted on a different server than the REST API.

for example:

```
frontend: http://frontend.com
RestApi:  http://ipaddress.com
```

I tried to enable the **CORS** in `.htaccess` and HTTP headers through PHP, to no avail.

Comment: It may be that they use different ports. Sorry but I don’t know codeigniter so I don’t know how to help.  Using different ports can cause CORS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS with php headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers)